# System.runAs for CspLitePortal Profile Users recently started returning no rows

Tags: unit-test, community, sharing

We have some tests that use `System.runAs` for a `User` created like this:

```
    Contact c = ...;

    Profile p = [
        select Id
        from Profile
        where UserType = 'CspLitePortal'
        limit 1
    ];  
    insert u = new User(
        ProfileId = p.id,
        ContactId = c.id,
        ...
    );
```

and they have started failing in the last 2 weeks. Seems like a sharing problem, where the test - running as a SA User - inserts rows, but the `System.runAs` User can't see them for custom objects and objects like Attachment.

Anyone else having this problem? Summer '19? Or a side effect of [Multi-Instance Core and Communities Service Disruption starting May 17, 2019](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312238&language=en_US&type=1)? Workarounds?

**PS**

Changing `with sharing` to `without sharing` eliminates the problem but is not a change that makes sense for production use.

Comment: Well, maybe this is somewhat related to Summer'19 changes regarding OWD [External Org-Wide Defaults in Orgs with Communities](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_networks_owd_cruc_enforced.htm) & [Custom Object Access Settings Default to Private](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_sharing_owd_custom.htm).

Comment: Hi @JefersonChaves, Looks likely: in a newly created scratch org all the custom objects have "Default External Access" as "private". Changing that now.

Comment: Yep @JefersonChaves that's it. Please post that as the answer and I will accept!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to Summer'19 changes:

- [OWD External Org-Wide Defaults in Orgs with Communities](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_networks_owd_cruc_enforced.htm)
- [Custom Object Access Settings Default to Private](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_sharing_owd_custom.htm)